# Rails 4: Sort by associated created_at if present, otherwise by parent's

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have an `Article` and `Comment` MVC - with the standard relationships.

I want to sort the articles in order based on the `Article` `created_at`, OR if the `Article` has `Comments`, then sort by the `Comments` `created_at`.

So far, I have:

```
@articles = Article.includes(:comments).order("comments.created_at desc")
```

What would I need to add to order the `Article` `created_at`, but only if the `Article` has no comments?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? (_MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc_)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `coalesce`:

```
@articles = Article.includes(:comments)
                   .order('coalesce(comments.created_at, articles.created_at) desc')
                   .references(:comments)
```

Comment: Thanks!! Genius! I just added .references(:comments) at the end for it to work!

Answer (score 0):

Take two different objects, one which have comments, the other which doesn't.

```
@articles_one = Article.includes(:comments).where('comments.id IS NOT NULL').order("comments.created_at desc")

@articles_two = Article.includes(:comments).where('comments.id IS NULL').order("articles.created_at desc")
```

Then, add the two objects to get the final required result.

```
@articles_final = @articles_one + @articles_two
```

Comment: I'm getting an error: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "comments" on @articles_one=.... any idea?

Comment: whats your article and comments relation ship?

Comment: once type the same line in console.

Comment: hai, whats the status?

Comment: hey sravan - i got it working, but the problem is that concatenating the arrays will not sort the articles with no comments WITH the articles with comments. right now, it simply just stacks the articles without comments after the articles with comments. i want to combine them together. hope you understand.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104696/discussion-between-sravan-and-gitastic).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve by this single query:

```
@articles = Article.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN ( SELECT article_id, MAX(created_at) AS max_created_at
                                             FROM comments
                                             GROUP BY article_id
                                           ) AS temp
                           ON temp.article_id = articles.id
                          ").order("CASE WHEN temp.max_created_at IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, articles.created_at")
```

**Explanation:**

- Sub query `temp` as `comments` was grouped by `article_id`
- `Article` left outer join with `temp` on `article_id`, so that means: `article` which doesn't have any `comment`, will have `max_created_at` = `NULL`
- We do order by `CASE WHEN temp.max_created_at IS NULL THEN 2 ELSE 1 END`, this means article has comments will be ordered by `max_created_at`, then articles haven't any comment will be ordered by `articles.created_at`

Comment: hey Hieu! Thanks for this. It sort of works. I implemented your code with a .reverse at the end, and it sorts everything, except that Articles with no comments still show up first.... any thoughts?

Comment: @gitastic: sorry for that, I recheck and update my answer, now I'm pretty sure it works :)